# Get string between parentheses in batch

Tags: batch-file

I just decided to learn a little batch.

So to do something useful I decided to create a script to organize my musics. They are all in this format:

Band (Album) - TrackNumber - TrackName

I want my script to create a folder with the band name and inside it the folder the albuns names. So I need to play with the filename but I don't know how to use the FINDSTR or any other method to get the string before the ´(´ and between the parentesis. How can I do that?

Comment: is this `Band (Album) - TrackNumber - TrackName` the file name or it's  a tag inside the mp3?

Comment: The filename. Like Band (Album) - TrackNumber - TrackName.mp3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some great resources to get you going:

**[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)** \
**[DosTips](http://www.dostips.com)** \
**[SS64](http://ss64.com/)** \
**[Rob van de Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php)** \
**[ComputerHope](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/commandi.htm)**

Here is an example of how to parse the string you listed.  Note that this example WILL NOT WORK if there are spaces within the band, album, or trackname.

```
for /f "delims=()- " %%A in ("Band (Album) - TrackNumber - TrackName") do (
    echo Band = "%%~A"
    echo Album = "%%~B"
    echo TrackNumber = "%%~C"
    echo TrackName = "%%~D"
)
```

Output:

```
Band = "Band"
Album = "Album"
TrackNumber = "TrackNumber"
TrackName = "TrackName"
```

However, this example will work with spaces by not using them as a delimiter.  Unfortunately this means that the spaces will not be trimmed from the results.

```
for /f "delims=()-" %%A in ("Band Name (Album) - Track Number - Track Name") do (
    echo Band = "%%~A"
    echo Album = "%%~B"
    echo TrackNumber = "%%~C"
    echo TrackName = "%%~D"
)
```

Output:

```
Band = "Band Name "
Album = "Album"
TrackNumber = " Track Number "
TrackName = " Track Name"
```

The spaces can be trimmed from the strings, but I will let you learn that technique :)
Hint, see the links above.

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess I can take it from here. Thanks for the explanation and the links, I will check it =)

Comment: My Result is: `Band = "Band Name "
Album = "%~B"
TrackNumber = "%~C"
TrackName = "%~D"`

Comment: @MarkDeven You should add `tokens=1-4` before the `delims`. By default the number of items that the for read from each line is 1.